# pip install census for census.gov API

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, census

I am very new to python, and I am trying to speak with the census.gov API to find the population of several zipcodes. I was able to get my API key, and I am using this python wrapper: https://github.com/datamade/census. I was able to install pip using the sudo easy_install pip command. Here's an example of the output when I run it again:

```
Best match: pip 9.0.1
Processing pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg
pip 9.0.1 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
Installing pip script to /usr/local/bin
Installing pip2.7 script to /usr/local/bin
Installing pip2 script to /usr/local/bin
Using /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for pip
Finished processing dependencies for pip
```

I am trying to use the commands:

```
pip install census
pip install us
```

`pip install us` seems to have worked, but I am getting a Traceback when trying `pip install census`:

```
Using cached census-0.8.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting requests>=1.1.0 (from census)
 Using cached requests-2.18.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting urllib3<1.22,>=1.21.1 (from requests>=1.1.0->census)
  Using cached urllib3-1.21.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting idna<2.6,>=2.5 (from requests>=1.1.0->census)
  Using cached idna-2.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17 (from requests>=1.1.0->census)
  Using cached certifi-2017.4.17-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 (from requests>=1.1.0->census)
  Using cached chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: urllib3, idna, certifi, chardet, requests, census
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 851, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 316, in clobber
    ensure_dir(destdir)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 83, in ensure_dir
    os.makedirs(path)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/urllib3'
```

I am not sure what to do. Can anyone help? I am using python 2.7.10 by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your user doesn't have write permissions on `/System/Library`. Either run `pip install` from the `root` user or use `pip install -u` to install the library to your own directory instead of the system one.